# How to trick Scala map method to produce more than one output per each input item?

Tags: scala

Quite complex algorith is being applied to list of Spark Dataset's rows (list was obtained using groupByKey and flatMapGroups). Most rows are transformed 1 : 1 from input to output, but in some scenarios require more than one output per each input. The input row schema can change anytime. The `map()` fits the requirements quite well for the 1:1 transformation, but is there a way to use it producing 1 : n output?

The only work-around I found relies on `foreach` method which has unpleasant overhed cause by creating the initial empty list (remember, unlike the simplified example below, real-life list structure is changing randomly).

My original problem is too complex to share here, but this example demonstrates the concept. Let's have a list of integers. Each should be transformed into its square value and if the input is even it should also transform into one half of the original value:

```
val X = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val y = X.map(x => x * x) //map is intended for 1:1 transformation so it works great here

val z = X.map(x => for(n <- 1 to 5) (n, x * x)) //this attempt FAILS - generates list of five rows with emtpy tuples

// this work-around works, but newX definition is problematic
var newX = List[Int]() //in reality defining as head of the input list and dropping result's tail at the end
val za = X.foreach(x => {
  newX = x*x :: newX
  if(x % 2 == 0) newX = (x / 2) :: newX
})

newX
```

Is there a better way than `foreach` construct?

Comment: I think `flatMap()` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.flatMap` produces any number of outputs from a single input.

```scala
val X = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

X.flatMap { x => 
  if (x % 2  == 0) Seq(x*x, x / 2) else Seq(x / 2) 
}
#=> Seq[Int] = List(0, 4, 1, 1, 16, 2, 2)
```

## flatMap in more detail

In `X.map(f)`, `f` is a function that maps each input to a single output. By contrast, in `X.flatMap(g)`, the function `g` maps each input to a *sequence* of outputs. `flatMap` then takes all the sequences produced (one for each element in `f`) and concatenates them.

The neat thing is `.flatMap` works not just for sequences, but for all sequence-like objects. For an option, for instance, `Option(x)#flatMap(g)` will allow `g` to return an `Option`. Similarly, `Future(x)#flatMap(g)` will allow `g` to return a Future.

Whenever the number of elements you return depends on the input, you should think of `flatMap`.